# How do we evaluate this infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given an infinite series:

$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\cos\bigl(A\ln(\frac{1}{n})\bigr)\cdot\bigl(\frac{1}{n}\bigr)^{1/2+B}$

where $A,B\in\mathbb{R^+}$

Calculate $S^2$.

Is there a simple plug and play formula/method for calculating the above (at least in the regions where it is convergent).

Can someone please help. I am totally lost with this one.

Answer (score 2):

Begin with this, where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s} = \left(1-2^{1-s}\right)\zeta(s)
$$
for $\mathrm{Re}\;s > 0$.  Then substitute $s=\frac{1}{2}+B+iA$.
Note
$$
\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/2+B+iA} = 
\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{iA}
\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/2+B} =
\exp\big(iA\log(1/n)\big)\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/2+B}
$$
so that
$$
\mathrm{Re}\;\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/2+B+iA} =
\cos\big(A\log(1/n)\big)\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/2+B}
$$
We conclude that
$$
S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\cos\bigl(A\ln(1/n)\bigr)\cdot\bigl(\frac{1}{n}\bigr)^{1/2+B} =
\mathrm{Re}\;\Bigg[\left(1-2^{1/2-B-iA}\right)\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+B+iA\right)\bigg]
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, it sort of seems to transform the problem from one infinite series to another. I am unsure how do i evaluate $S^2$ using $S=
\mathrm{Re}\;\Bigg[\left(1-2^{1/2-B-iA}\right)\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+B+iA\right)\bigg]$ as zeta is again an infinite series..

Comment: pardon my ignorance..